# How to apply getServerSideProps and react-query for prefecthing data in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

I'm beginner of NextJS. I want to make notice board.

Now,

1. When I click prev or next button `router.push(?page=${currentPage})`
2. Then, `getServerSideProps` get query and request (GET) to server to get currentPage data
3. `getServerSideProps` returns data -> in page notice, I use useQuery (react-query)

Then, in this situation, the problem is:

when I click next button, `getServerSideProps` => correctly gets currentPageData!

**BUT**: react-query data disappeared with reactqueryDevTools...

It doesn't work correctly.

I want to prefecth nextPageData and show currentPageData using getServerSideProps and react-query.

How can I solve it?

This is my code:

// page/notice/index.tsx

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const res = await getNotices(context.query.page)
  const data = res.data

  return {
    props: { result: data },
  }
}

export async function getNotices(page) {
  return await api.get(`/admin/notice?page=${page}`)
}

export default function Notice({ result }) {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()
  const { isLoading, data } = useQuery(
    ['notices', result.currentPage],
    () => getNotices(result.currentPage),
    {
      initialData: result,
      select: (data) => data.data,
    },
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    const nextPage = result.currentPage + 1
    queryClient.prefetchQuery(['notices', nextPage], () => getNotices(nextPage))
    console.log('reactQueryData', data)
  }, [result, queryClient])
...
```